Can i call steps within step definitions in cucumber-jvm
I found this answer here:
To call steps within step definitions, inherit cuke4duke.Steps in java

import cuke4duke.StepMother;
import cuke4duke.Steps;
import cuke4duke.annotation.I18n.EN.When;

public class CallingSteps extends Steps {
    public CallingSteps(StepMother stepMother) {
        super(stepMother);
    }

    @When("^I call another step$")
    public void iCallAnotherStep() {
        Given("it is magic"); // This will call a step defined somewhere else.
    }
}

I know that cuke4duke got defunkt 12 years ago and in here saying Cucumber-JVM is the successor, so does something like this exist in Cucumber-JVM?
I want to call step within a step definition by is name that run that step inside try and documant if there is exeption, like this(kotlin):
@When("soft call the step {string})
    fun softCall(stepToCall: String) {
        runCatching {
            Given(stepToCall) // This will call the step defined somewhere else.
        }.onFailure {//documant}
    }

That will let me run every step in my project as a "soft" version of himself, that not fail the scenario and skip all the other steps. All by only one step/fun to maintain that not need to be update to every new step

AFAIK you can't in the way you expect to but why not call the method annotated @Given("stepToCall") directly?

miss type. I meant Given(stepToCall). Using a verable string to run a given step

You'll have to implement a method that kinda does the switch to find which method to call for which string.

That mean every time I add a step or change one I need to update the method? Because that something I want to avoid, also I have a lot of steps in the project.
